# Accessing Stylesheet Rules for CSS Loaded From CDN

Tags: javascript, css, svg

I'm currently working on converting browser-drawn SVG to PNG. In order to do this, I wrap the SVG data into an Image, write it to a Canvas, then use its data URI to open it in a new window as a PNG.

Moreover, I need to inline styling information. To do this, I iterate over each of the stylesheet's rules and check if any are used in the SVG. If it is used, I inline it. I learned this approach from [this article](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2014/01/21/convert-svg-to-png/).

This works on my local machine, which doesn't use a CDN. On our production server, we're using Cloudfront to serve up CSS/Images, however, CSS files aren't actually loaded into document.styleSheets, apart from a place-holder with an href pointing to where they're located on Cloudfront.

How can I access these stylesheets? They must exist somewhere in the browser, if they're being used in the DOM.

Thanks

Comment: I'm guessing that this is a domain issue - try looking into CORS: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cors.html

Answer (score 0):

This is long overdue, but thanks for pointing me in the right direction Steve Sanders. Here's an explanation of what I tried.

This approach **didn't** work: I edited the CORS settings of the s3 bucket hosting our assets such that cross-origin `GET` requests are allowed, then tried to make an ajax request to the cdn to get the css files I needed. My browser complained about cross-origin resource sharing, and it didn't work.

This approach **did** work: Because I couldn't make an ajax request to our cdn, instead I made an ajax request to our web server (same origin). Although it isn't ideal to get assets from your web server, it works.